# SQLITE update multiple row from stock where we have a product with multiple record

Tags: sqlite

I want to create a trigger for product table to update qty after selling product .

I have a table of product like this productTB with name and qty fields :

| NAME | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 'A' | 1 |
| 'B' | 4 |
| 'A' | 4 |

I want to write a query for remove 2 qty for 'A' item.

I want the qty of 'A' item  be like this

| NAME | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 'A' | 0 |
| 'B' | 4 |
| 'A' | 3 |

How can do this in SQLite?

Comment: This data sample is junk

Comment: It could be also: (A,1), (B,4), (A,2) if you deduct 2 units of A, so you need a business rule for your trigger.

Comment: @JHH, you comment suggests you do not have a clue about SQL.

Comment: @PChemGuy why is junk ?? i just show you a simple thing how to update a data that have more than one record

Comment: Well, I do not know, maybe it has something to do with the fact that however hard I try to see the difference between lines #1 and #3 in a table of THREE rows, I cannot distinguish them. Perhaps I miss something really obvious...

Comment: @PChemGuy I have 2 record of 'A' the first one is 1 qty the second is 4 i want if i sell two 'A' product the first recored will be 0 and the second record of 'A' will be 3

Comment: So, I do not miss anything... But I am not sure how to respond. Perhaps you should, I do not know, start actually doing some studying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the business rule is to deduct inventory from the least quantity and we have the following inventory for product 'A':

```
name|qty|
----+---+
A   |  1|
A   |  3|
A   |  5|
A   |  7|
A   |  9|
```

Now there's a sales of 8 product 'A', which we need to deduct the inventory in the following order:

```
name|qty| qty to be deducted|balance|
----+---+-------------------+-------+
A   |  1|                  1|      0|
A   |  3|                  3|      0|
A   |  5|                  4|      1|
A   |  7|                  0|      7|
A   |  9|                  0|      9|
```

Step 1. Calculate cumulative qty of product A with window function:

```sql
select name,
       qty,
       sum(qty) over (partition by name order by qty) as c_qty
  from ka
 where name = 'A';
```

We get: (`cqty` is cumulative qty)

```
name|qty|cqty|
----+---+----+
A   |  1|   1|
A   |  3|   4|
A   |  5|   9|
A   |  7|  16|
A   |  9|  25|
```

Step 2. So we need to allocate / deduct inventory qty from the first three rows, but how many? Let us do some calculation:

```sql
with cte_inv as (
select name,
       qty,
       sum(qty) over (partition by name order by qty) as cqty
  from ka
 where name = 'A')
select name,
       qty,
       cqty,
       case when cqty < 8 then qty else qty - (cqty - 8) end as aqty
  from cte_inv
 where aqty >=0;
```

We get: (`aqty` is allocated / deducted qty)

```
name|qty|cqty|aqty|
----+---+----+----+
A   |  1|   1|   1|
A   |  3|   4|   3|
A   |  5|   9|   4|
```

Step 3. Now we know how many (`aqty`) to be deducted from the product 'A' inventory and we can update the table. However, before we can do that we need to be able to identify each row individually. The table schema doesn't have a primary key. What we can do is to take advantage of sqlite's capability `rowid`, which is a unique identifier for each row in a table. In this case, we do a select from the product inventory table:

```sql
select rowid, * from ka;
```

And, we get the following:

```
rowid|name|qty|
-----+----+---+
    1|A   |  1|
    2|A   |  3|
    3|A   |  5|
    4|A   |  7|
    5|A   |  9|
```

Okay, we have a unique key to identify each row and we can proceed and update the table accordingly by combine the above queries as CTE (Common Table Express) into one single query as below:

```sql
with cte_inv as (
select rowid as pkey,
       name,
       qty,
       sum(qty) over (partition by name order by qty) as cqty
  from ka
 where name = 'A'),
cte_ainv as (
select pkey,
       name,
       qty,
       cqty,
       case when cqty < 8 then qty else qty - (cqty - 8) end as aqty
  from cte_inv
 where aqty >=0)
update ka
   set qty = qty - (select aqty from cte_ainv where pkey = ka.rowid)
 where rowid <= (select max(pkey) from cte_ainv);

select * from ka;
```

Outcome:

```
name|qty|
----+---+
A   |  0|
A   |  0|
A   |  1|
A   |  7|
A   |  9|
```

Now you can see the inventory was updated correctly.

There're some concepts introduced in this practice:

- window function to get cumulative qty: `sum() over (partition by name order by qty) as city`
- Common Table Expression (CTE)
- `rowid` as primary key if not available.

Suggestion: Modify the table schema to have a primary key defined. In sqlite3, we can walk around the design issue with `rowid`. However, it's not a best practice.